# Linear combination of atomic orbitals

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, superposition, orbitals, quantum-chemistry

For example, I have linear combination of states $$|n,l,m\rangle:~| \psi \rangle = c_1 |2,1,0\rangle + c_2 |2,1,-1\rangle +c_3 |2,1,1\rangle $$. Here $n =2$, $l = 1$, so it's three p-orbitals with different orientation in space. Is it possible to deduce the resulting shape of this linear combination depending on the coefficients $c_i$ in this basis set? In general?

Comment: You can find $\langle r|nlm\rangle $  to deduce the shape of the wave function on a coordinate basis.